# HTML5 download attribute not changing filename

Tags: html, attributes, download

I'm having issues with the download attribute and overwriting the filename. Currently when I set a value for the download attribute it is not taking affect. I believe this as something to do with the specific file I am referencing as it works for other files, but I'm not sure exactly what is causing the issue or how to resolve.

In the below code the filename does not get overridden. (I stole the code straight from W3Schools to keep the example very basic and to ensure nothing I am doing is creating the issue.)

Additional, the download only works in Chrome. If you try in Firefox it opens the file to play the video (which is another issue that I need to resolve).

```
<a href="https://cameratag.com/videos/v-c1e97800-8f2b-0132-12e6-22000a8c0328/qvga/mp4.mp4" download="w3logo22">
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I contacted the content provider and determined the issue is due to the fact the assets URLs are actually redirects to a signed URL on their CDN.